# Should I use IT or THEM?

Tags: singular-vs-plural, reflexive-pronouns

> [...] tonnes of rubbish are being accumulated and the lack of space for (IT/THEM) is becoming a complex problem.

Should it be IT or THEM? And why?

Comment: In general, you should include the complete sentence or paragraph for complete context.

Comment: **it** (the antecedent is "rubbish") would be fine unless you were talking specifically about a tonnage limit.  Also, consider **are accumulating** as an alternative to **are being accumulated**.